# UNIX timestamp displays different date depending on timezone using Moment.js

Tags: momentjs, unix-timestamp

I understand that UNIX is timezone independent. However, users from different countries are seeing different dates. For example I have a unix timestamp of 1545004800 (December 17th) which a user from Amsterdam submitted, but as a user in Los Angeles, I see the formatted date of December 16th.

I use the following line to convert the timestamp to a format like `Dec 17, 2018`

`this.date = moment.unix(this.album.submissionReleaseDate).format("MMM DD, YYYY");`

where `this.album.submissionReleaseDate` is `1545004800`. Since the value is unix, it is timezone independent so why do I see a different date compared to my user in Amsterdam?

Here's a quick video where I show different timezones and how that affects the date that is displayed: https://youtu.be/-F7pieTljnc

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fix was to do something like this instead:

`this.date = moment.utc(moment.unix(this.album.submissionReleaseDate)).format("MMM DD, YYYY");`